# PageReference.getContent()

Tags: apex

I am trying to send an attachment as PDF and rendering it from a VF page. I have a form wherein I input values and then hit save and send button. Now what happens is the values get saved and then it calls the function to generate PDF and send it (All in same transaction) but I am getting

> System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0.

I checked if the record is getting created in before the generating the PDF and it does.

Now if I save the record in a separate transaction and then call the function to generate PDF (separate transaction) it works fine.

Is this a case that where record is partially saved till the transaction is complete ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Have you enabled critical updates from winter 16 release? Because in new release, getContentAsPdf is now treated as callout and you can call it in `@future` method I hope it will get the committed record.
2. If you did not enabled then, you can not send call getContentAsPdf from @future, because this method is not supported in @future method.
3. In this case, you need to create a method exposed as REST service, and call it from your apex class.
4. You can see the code below to achieve

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/sendPDFEmail')
Global class GETPDFContent{
    @HttpPost
    global static void sendEmail(String EmailIdCSV, String Subject, String body) {

        List<String> EmailIds = EmailIdCSV.split(',');

        PageReference ref = Page.PDF_DEMO;
        Blob b = ref.getContentAsPDF();

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa1 = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        efa1.setFileName('attachment_WORK.pdf');
        efa1.setBody(b);

        String addresses;
        email.setSubject( Subject +String.valueOf(DateTime.now()));
        email.setToAddresses( EmailIds  );
        email.setPlainTextBody(Body);
        email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa1});
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});

    }
}
```

And call this rest Api From this class like below:

```
public class SendVFAsAttachment{

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void sendVF(String EmailIdCSV, String Subject,String recordId,String userSessionId)
    {
        //Initialize your page with recordId and call
        //Blob data = page.getContentAsPdf
        //Replace below URL with your Salesforce instance host
        String addr = 'your salesforceurl/services/apexrest/sendPDFEmail';
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint( addr );
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + userSessionId);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');

        Map<String,String> postBody = new Map<String,String>();
        postBody.put('EmailIdCSV',EmailIdCSV);
        postBody.put('Subject',Subject);
        postBody.put('body',data);
        String reqBody = JSON.serialize(postBody);

        req.setBody(reqBody);
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse response = http.send(req);
    }
}
```

Now call this class from your VF page controller like this:

```
SendVFAsAttachment.sendVF('emailaddress1@email.com,emailaddress2@email.com','Sample Test from Trigger',
    recordId,UserInfo.getSessionId());
```

I hope this will help you :)
You can ask me for more help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're correct. If this were all happening in the same execution context the save wouldn't be "committed" to the database until AFTER the getcontentAsPDF call had been made, which would of course cause an exception of some kind since nothing would be returned.

You could possibly put this into an @future call made from your page controller and process it that way if you don't want to require two button clicks. The @future call would query for the record after it had been committed to do the getContentAsPDF() retrieval and complete the rest of your transaction for you. You could connect up all of the right pieces of code to have it do the send it for you too.